# Git causing confusion

Tags: git

I have some Git-related doubt.

I have done some changes from master branch and by mistake I have commited to master branch. I did:

```
git add.
git commit "my changed"
```

But I could not push to the master branch due to some issues. So I have created another branch and from that branch I did push. But I was getting conflicts.

So my doubts are:

1. If I created a new branch again from master whether I will have all committed changes from the master?
2. What step do I need to follow to fix this conflict?
3. What do I need to do to make my master branch as same as server?
4. If I clone the project again, will it have my committed changes or same as server?

Can I do like? Clone again the master, checkout to the branch I got conflict,
do:

```
git merge master
```

From there and fix the conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just hit `git log` to find if you have all commits from master if your HEAD is ahead or at same level as master which means you have all commits from master (or) If you have created a branch from master
   `git checkout master`
   `git checkout -b new-branch`
   then YES.
2. When you have conflicts you have to resolve using
   `git mergetool`
   Check `git status` whether you have resolved your conflicts
3. If you want to get local master reset to remote master branch
   `git checkout -B master origin/master`
4. If you had pushed the commit on other branch instead of master, it will be on the remote other branch not on origin/master. 
   So when you are pushing new changes to remote custom branch, 
   `git fetch origin master`
   `git checkout custom-branch`
   `git rebase -i origin/master`
   `git commit -m 'Your new feature stuff'`
   `git push origin custom-branch`
   This will only push to remote custom-branch not to master.
   Create a merge request for merging to remote master.

Answer (score 0):

1. If i created a new branch again from master whether i will have all
   committed changes from the master?

> Yes

2. What step i need to follow to fix this conflict?

> EIther rebase/merge your branch withh/into master and resolve the
>   conflicts using

```
git rebase origin/master 
git merge origin/master
```

3. What i need to do to make my master branch as same as server?

> Reset the branch with master using

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

4. if i clone the project again , will it have my commiitted changes or
   same as server?

> Yes

To conclude, in order to resolve your problems on the branch currently, you should do the following

```
git checkout branchA
git merge origin/master // resolve conflicts here
git commit
git push
```

Comment: git reset --hard origin/master : if i do this, will i lose all changes what i have done? will it be available in the branch from where i sent the Pull request?

Comment: Yes. `git reset --hard origin/master` will make your currently checked out branch commit-wise look like `origin/master`. It will also destroy any uncommitted changes you may have. Make sure you have a backup just in case.